# Is 'false' a valid return type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function that always returns false:

```
function alwaysReturnsFalse(): boolean {
  // some code
  return false;
}
```

I'd like to make that clear by using `false` instead of `boolean`:

```
function alwaysReturnsFalse(): false {
  // some code
  return false;
}
```

TypeScript seems to accept this when I try it, but is that bad practice? I couldn't find any examples, or anything in the TypeScript documentation about it, so I'm guessing I probably shouldn't do it. I've never heard of `false` being a type. But, I think it would make the code a lot more understandable at a glance, especially for a more complex function that returns say, a Promise or false.

Thank you!

Comment: *I'd like to make that clear by using false instead of boolean* - May i know why ? What will be the use case of it ?

Comment: I don't think it will be bad practice. If it helps you to solve proble why don't do it.

Comment: It's called "literal types": https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I have simplified the function for this example but for my real use case the function is longer. I think it would be easier for a developer who is unfamiliar with the code to parse what is going on if they knew that `false` was expected, instead of `true` or `false` (if the return type were `boolean`). I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @zerkms Oh, that's great, some solid documentation! I was not able to find that on my own. Thank you very much, super helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can define the return type of a function in TS as a single primitive value. This is kind of a trivial example, but the basic functionality of constraining variables to specific, finite sets of values allows you to carefully control the expectations of a piece of functionality. This is an approach that is simpler and easier-to-use than enums, so it's good to be familiar with.

A multiple-value example sheds more light:

```
type chalkColor = "red" | "yellow" | "green" | "blue" ;

const getRandomColor = (): chalkColor => {
  //Just returns a random color.
  //You are assured it's one of only 4 possible values.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*TypeScript seems to accept this when I try it, but is that bad practice?* - No, there is nothing wrong in passing the primitive value `false` as a return type but I am just thinking is the function still required if it is always going to return false.

Can not we directly use `false` instead of calling this function ?

```
function alwaysReturnsFalse(): false {
  return false;
}

const res = alwaysReturnsFalse();
```

**OR**

```
const res = false;
```

Which solution will you prefer ? I think second one right as it is more compatible/less code.

Comment: Imagine some code accepts `() => bool` function, and you need to define one to pass.

Comment: @zerkms Yes in that case we have to pass any default value but here OP specially said that this function will always return false. Based on that i answered. Sorry if it does not make sense.

Comment: If you need to create a function that returns a false value, how _else_ would you define it?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I see what you are saying for sure. My main question was just if `false` could be a return type in typescript, so I wanted to provide a really simple example with no nuance. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @gabriellend Now after reading your comments I understood the problem statement. Yes, you can use `false` as a return type in Typescript.